# Jumping to a specific point in a web page AND passing $_GET variables for php?

Tags: php, html, url, dom

**Edit:**

Well, as I mentioned in a comment, for reasons I can't explain, the "correct" method which was originally crashing my page as I stated below, now appears to be working just fine... UGH!

That's two hours of my life I'll never get back...lol At least now I know for sure that the # always goes at the end! :)

Thanks for the help everyone!

**Original question:**

Ok, so I have come across an issue where either I'm doing it wrong, or it just can't be done, but I'm not sure which!

I have a content area in the middle of a web page marked like this:

```
<div id="content>
   include($_GET['page'].'.php');
</div>
```

The page loads different content depending on which $_GET variable is passed in the URL. On one of my pages, I have a form where when a user clicks the submit button, it redirects to this page... so I need to pass the name of the content file to load in the URL. It has been working fine like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/my_page?page=value
```

Now, I need it to also go directly to the content position on the page...

So here's the problem:

THIS works to jump to the location:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/my_page#content
```

..but THIS code below *doesn't* work because I get a php undefined index error when I try to access the $_GET variable:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/my_page#content?page=value
```

just for fun, I tried this...(because I couldn't remember if the # was supposed to go before or after the ? in the URL)

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/my_page?page=value#content
```

...which crashed the page, so clearly that's not it either.

Any ideas? I can't imagine this can't be done, so I have to believe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Is it totally necessary to submit the form by passing the data in the url as $ _GET and not using $ _POST?

Comment: Basically, the form is Posting the variables from the form itself.  The GET variable is the name of the php file to be loaded into the "content" area.  I have an include() inside those <div> tags. Good question though.  I'm going to edit the question to explain it better.

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you try `http://www.mywebsite.com/my_page?variable=value#content`? this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: It seems like that should work, but the error I'm getting is an undefined index on any line of code that tries to access the $_GET variable.

Comment: Well.. for reasons I can't explain. The "correct" answer is no longer generating error messages or crashing the page... so it now appears to be working.  I have NO idea what I did wrong before.

These are the days when I hate technology...lol

Thanks for the help guys!